# Full Screen Notification

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

I want to make App Like Uber But I Don't know how to make full screen notification,When Driver receiver new Request a new Screen Pop up   that will show  timer ,accept , reject button. even when driver app is in background ,
I am newbiew 
here is a video link what i want to do
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dhqSDexUKYY---ARHjWcg3bM0tYWRmLo/view?usp=sharing

Sorry for English

I have tried to use heads up notification with full screen but it didn't work well ;
I have tried to make background service to but i am not good in it so that also did not go well;
I am working on Oreo ;

Comment: Full-screen notification is not a better solution, you can call activity when a notification arrives.

Comment: how to call an activity when notification arrive without clicking on notification . as shown in video... thanks for reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using this code to open an activity when the notification comes when my application is running mode. if your activity in background mode you can use a service to open a particular activity.

```
 @Override
        public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
            // Create and show notification
            String strForResponse = remoteMessage.getData().toString();
            Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
            strForResponse = strForResponse.substring(1, strForResponse.length() - 1);           //remove curly brackets
            String[] keyValuePairs = strForResponse.split(",");              //split the string to creat key-value pairs
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
            for (String pair : keyValuePairs)                        //iterate over the pairs
            {
                String[] entry = pair.split("=");                   //split the pairs to get key and value
                map.put(entry[0].trim(), entry[1].trim());              //add them to the hashmap and trim whitespaces
                try {
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(map);
                    System.out.println("Firebase Notification Responce:" + obj.toString());
                    destination = obj.getString("destination");
                    source = obj.getString("source");
                    source_override = obj.getString("source_override");


                } catch (Throwable t) {

                }
        }
                Intent intent = new Intent(MyFirebaseMessagingService.this,"Class Name".class);
                intent.putExtra("destination", destination);
                intent.putExtra("source", source);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
```

Comment: thank you man. but i tried  to start service for  activity . issue is i am not able to start that service in onMessageRecive();

Comment: i am trying my best to explian sorry i am new here ; i have given link for the video too if it help

Comment: Refer This Link: https://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~campbell/cs65/lecture19/lecture19.html